# Original Filename of a block in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Does anyone know how I can get the original filename of a block in hdfs? I'm trying to write a BlockReplacementPolicy. When the file is being written for the first time, I can use srcPath parameter to get the filename. However, when under replicated blocks are being replicated again, I believe srcPath is not going to solve my problem.

Do you know any class that I can use to get the filename for a block (and/or block collection)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BlockManager` service in HDFS is agnostic of what file the block belongs to. As far as am aware, there isn't a reverse mapping of `BlockID` -> `INode` as the architecture of HDFS has never needed it and is expensive to maintain for only a few special purposes.

You will likely need to build this mapping on your own, as an internal or external service; for example, as a program that reverse-indexes the persisted `fsimage` file periodically and serves it.